# I want to add multiple job roles for different durations in designation history table . how can i get it in ABAP?

Tags: abap, database-table

I have 2 tables i.e employee details and employee designation history.

```
Employee details table - EMPID , Name , Age ,Gender. (EmpID - Primary Key)

Designation history table - EMPID , Startdate , Enddate , JobRole.
```

I know there needs to be one more key in designation history table to add multiple records for given employee ID ,which one should i use ?

So that i can get output like this  -
Sumedh was  Associated SAP developer from 2021 - 2022
then from 2022 - 2024 he was sr. Developer
then again got demoted to Associate sap developer in 2024-25.

Comment: Please propose the code you tried, tell us exactly the issue you have. Stack Overflow doesn't accept questions asking for recommendations.

Comment: sorry about that ,i actually wanted recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just omitted the `MANDT` field for brevity. It needs to be the first of every tables primary key if you want your table to be client-specified. What follows next? Well, there are several options:

Option 1: use `EMPID` and `Startdate` as primary key. You see that a lot being used in older SAP database schemas, like table `ADRP`, for example. This of course assumes that nobody will be reassigned more than once per day.

Option 2: Add another column which counts the assignments for that employee. Then the primary key would be `EMPID` and `ASSIGNMENT_NUM`.

Option 3: Do it like BOPF does. Instead of wondering what the primary key *should* be, give every table a single primary key field `DB_KEY` which is a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), generated the moment the database entry is generated (You can use the class `cl_system_uuid` for generating them). Then never worry about primary keys again.

Which one is "the best" option? Sorry, but that's more of a religious question.

Comment: I thought of making Startdate as primary key as well but i think i read somewhere that its not a good idea to make dates as primary key? is that true?

Comment: @sumedhpatil There are no absolute truths in software architecture. Every design has advantages or disadvantages which might or might not matter for your particular use-case.

Comment: I will go with startdate as primary key then. Thank you so much.